# What was the last live concert the Beatles played together?

Tags: history, concert, the-beatles

What was the last concert/show John Lennon, Paul McCartney, George Harrison and Ringo Starr played together as the Beatles?

Answer (score 13):

The last regular concert of the Beatles where they performed a full concert set and tickets were sold to the public was August 29, 1966 at Candlestick Park in San Francisco.

The January 1969 appearance on the rooftop of the Apple Corps building in London was a private live performance in front of a small invited audience. Tickets were not sold to the public. It was a one-time event, two-and-a-half years after they had ceased touring and performing.

Answer (score 4):

[They played a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles%27_rooftop_concert) on the rooftop of Apple Corps Ltd. in London at the end of January, 1969. This was reportedly their final live show ever.